# Как получить минимальное значение и имя из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, list, dict

У меня есть парсер из которого я получаю данные цену и имя. Далее добавляю их в list:

```
list.append(
                    {
                        "min.name": name,
                        "min.price": price
                    }
                )
Результат:
[{'min.name': 'Apple iPhone 12 128GB Black Neverlock', 'min.price': '23 999'}, {'min.name': 'iPhone IPhone XR xr Айфон хр Хр Iphone black', 'min.price': '14 400'}, ...]
```

Мне нужно сравнить min.price определить самую низкую цену, а далее получить название товара к которому относиться самая низкая цена и вывести эти данные примерно так: "Название" "Цена"

Comment: И в чем конкретная проблема?

Comment: Я могу получить минимальную цену но связанное с ним имя нет

Comment: Не следует называть список именем list - это зарезервированное слово языка python

Answer (score 1):

```py
l = [{'min.name': 'Apple iPhone 12 128GB Black Neverlock', 'min.price': '23 999'}, {'min.name': 'iPhone IPhone XR xr Айфон хр Хр Iphone black', 'min.price': '14 400'}]

m = min(l, key=lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x.get('min.price')))))
print(m)
# {'min.name': 'iPhone IPhone XR xr Айфон хр Хр Iphone black', 'min.price': '14 400'}

print(*m.values())
# iPhone IPhone XR xr Айфон хр Хр Iphone black 14 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен смысл, зачем делать список из словарей с одинаковыми ключами?
Почему не:

```python
data = {'min.name': [], 'min.price': []}
data['min.name'].append(name)
data['min.price'].append(price)
```

Ну или из того что есть собрать
(list лучше не использовать в качесве переменной, но пусть будет как в примере):

```python
data = {'min.name': [], 'min.price': []}
for l in list:
    data['min.name'].append(l['min.name'])
    data['min.price'].append(l['min.price'])
```

Затем поиск значительно упростится, а именно:

```python
minimum_price = min(data['min.price'])
data['min.name'].index(minimum_price)
# Или одной строкой
data['min.name'].index(min(data['min.price']))
```

Да и DataFrame в Pandas с таким форматом собирается на раз. По сути у Вас ключи это название колонок, а для названий колонок рядами будут списки.